# Appending multiple rows from a source sheet to a destination sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using code from this older thread to copy a range of cells from a source sheet and paste them to the last row of a destination sheet.
https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm04B0WxqiEJns/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2F4B0WxqiEJns

The suggested code copies and pastes the data on the same sheet so I attempted (and failed) to modify it:

```
function appendEagleData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Eagle New Rows");
  var dest = ss.getSheetByName("Eagle Static Data")
  var source = sh.getRange("A4:J20");
  var v = source.getValues();
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
}
```

...Clearly, I'm a little out of my depth.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
function appendEagleData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Eagle New Rows");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(4,1,sh1.getLastRow()-3,10);
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Eagle Static Data")
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1);
  rg1.copyTo(rg2);  
}
```

try this:

```
function appendEagleData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Eagle New Rows");
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(4,1,getColumnHeight(2,sh1,ss)-3,10);
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Eagle Static Data")
  var rg2=sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1);
  rg1.copyTo(rg2);  
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}
```

Comment: To expand on Cooper's answer, [here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) for `copyTo()`

Comment: Thanks!  I have one modification I need to make.  rg1 need to be dynamic in terms of how many rows of data there are to copy.  I tried: var rg1 = sh1.getRange(4,1,sh1.getLastRow(),10);  but that didn't work becasue there are formulas in columns off to the right.  Columns A and B are data from an external API.  Can I set the number of rows to the last row in column B with data only?

Comment: Hey @Cooper.  Thank you so much for responding.  Its great to have this resource as I start to try and learn some coding.  I ended up using something a little different.  I can't seem to paste the code in these comments but it seems to be working so far.  The getcolumnheight function you suggested was a little too hard for me to follow... for now.  As i learn, I intend to come back to it and try to understand what it's doing.  Thanks again.